# Orientdb - Adding Formula to Vertex (Node)

Tags: orientdb

I am new to Orientdb. I have use case of trying to create a financial model in Orientdb . Is it possible to create a formula field type on a vertex that is based on another linked vertex or vertex and edge value .  If not possible i am interested in best practice of how to update Vertex field values based on another vertex .

Comment: Do you looking some similar to Stored Procedures in SQL? http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Functions.html